# How can I send data from Parse backend and display it in Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

How can I send a value from Parse that is linked to a UserId in GA and view it there under the User who created it?

My Parse backend stores various data values that I want to integrate with GA values. In my app Users can create followers to email. For example, I can use my app to create various follower values with their emails. A user has a UserID created by GA and this value will be linked to every follower that user creates. I can then choose a follower and email them.

I'm trying to send the count of number of supporters that a user creates from Parse to GA. So, I would go to GA and be able to view how many followers were created by a user(UserId) per day. I'm accessing a view in my staging build that allows me to see UserIds. I've been trying to use Data Import in GA to create a custom analytics import and having the values in CSV. This method can be found here http://cutroni.com/blog/2013/10/30/dimension-widening-import-data-directly-into-google-analytics/.

However, I have not been able to figure out how to properly set key and import values so that GA can start tracking followers created by users. In GA's Data Import I can't get the key value to be UserId, yet I can see the UserIds given to users GA through the User Exploration tab.

How can I set up the Data Import to view UserIds and assign all followers created by that user from Parse?

Comment: you need to create a custom dimension for your Userid.  The user id that is part of google analytics is for internal use its not something you can see in the reports.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying that. How long should it take for me to see results when I upload a CSV? @DaImTo

Comment: isnt easier to use Firebase Analytics?